# Selecting multiple items on the web

Tags: design-patterns, select

I need some ideas for a design problem, i have the need for a user to complete a task that involves selecting one or more teachers, and then one or more students before submitting. The list of possible students will typically be less than 20, but could be up to 100. Any ideas how i should go about this? I am thinking a whole bunch of check boxes, but this could be problematic if there are a 100 students, it would take a long time to find the required students, and it would take up a lot of space.

Comment: This is better suited for http://ui.stackexchange.com IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for picking N entries from a large list is the following GUI widget:

- A list of items to select from
- A search field above it for filtering list contents
- A second list showing currently selected items (with "delete from list" button(s))

The following is a great example of how the first 2 items can look: 
http://kilianvalkhof.com/uploads/listfilter/

The mechanics of that example are : http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/

Another example (less polished looking but still a good design in some ways) is http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/filterlist/index.php/all

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a select list with the multiple attribute?

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="...">...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you like bunch of checkboxes but not all in 1 column, but in table. I mean, for example 4-5 columns of checkboxes. It wouldn't be so huge